# ACE Editor: expressions that aren't references to named arguments

Tags: javascript, r, regex, ace-editor

I'm working on an ACE editor mode based on the existing R-language mode.  There are a set of expressions that I'm applying special syntax highlighting for, but I don't want to detect them when that expression appears as an argument name reference.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated...

As an example, say the expression I'm trying to match is "my_var".

I DO want to match it the following cases:

`3 * (my_var + 2)`

`some_fun(my_var)`

`some_other_fun(a=my_var)`

What I do not want to match is when "my_var" is an argument name

`some_fun(my_var=1)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to edit your highlight mode to include special tags, but to disable that highlighting for parameter names. As an example,

```
circle( cxy=c(10,20), r= 30, filter=filter(...), ...)
```

should highlight only the 2nd occurrence of *filter*.

If so, then assuming that the user is an R programmer **who uses <- for assignment and not =**, the fix is easy: insert into *this.rules* section of  your  *xxx_highlight_rules.js* file.

```
{
        token: ["identifier", "keyword.operator"],
         regex : "([a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z0-9._]*\\b)(=)"
 },
```

above the *onMatch : function(value)* which identifies the special tags.

For an example see: [//github.com/mslegrand/ptRAceBldr/blob/master/TrestleTech/ace/lib/ace/mode/ptr_highlight_rules.js](http://github.com/mslegrand/ptRAceBldr/blob/master/TrestleTech/ace/lib/ace/mode/ptr_highlight_rules.js)

Comment: An interesting solution made more interesting by the fact that, in this use case, there will likely be no assignment performed.  Thanks, I will ponder your suggestion further...